# Merge two rows that share duplicate field using sql

Tags: sql, merge, duplicates

Good afternoon everyone,

This is my first question, hop i'll be clear enough. I am trying to merge duplicate rows that share some identical field. Not all fields are similar, but the only thing that makes more rws are null values.

There is for exemple the result I get :

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>ALIAS 1</th>
    <th>ALIAS 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MPE</td>
    <td>3333</td>
    <td>Null</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MPE</td>
    <td>3333</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Null</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the result I would like to have :

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>ALIAS 1</th>
    <th>ALIAS 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MPE</td>
    <td>3333</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is an example to simplify, but in reality my request looks more like :

[SQL REQUEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG4HM.png)

And I have Multiple rows for One same ID. I am pretty sure that there is a way to merge these result into one signle row by replacing null values by the values that contain a real value.

Do not esitate to ask if you need more precision. I am really thankful to you. I search a lot already in this website but nothing is working...

I tried to group the values, thanks to Yogesh Sharma for his answer. But the thing is :

As "Null" Is a value, the group by expression is not suffisent to merge celles by deleting the "null" value. What would be great is a group by expression that don't take "null" as a value.

See below :

[GROUP BY EXPRESSION RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLaks.png)

Have a really nice day.

Matteo

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

Just do aggregation :

```
select name, id, max(alias1), max(alias2)
from table t
group by name, id;
```

**EDIT** : Use case expression to considered the text `null` as `NULL` :

```
select name, id, 
       max(case when alias1 = 'null' then null else alias1 end), 
       max(case when alias2 = 'null' then null else alias2 end)
from table t
group by name, id;
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you a lot for your quick answer. Unfortunatly. As "Null" Is a value, the group by expression is not suffisent to merge celles by deleting the "null" value. What would be great is a group by expression that don't take "null" as a value.

Comment: @MatteoOcchipinti. . . You need `case` expression inside `max()` function.

Comment: I think it's a little bit more complicate because I already used MAX and CASE to Pivot the table. Before rotating the table, there s no null value, all rows is a duplicate row with a different date and I pivot it to have all the date in the same row. But Maybe my question was not well asked. I will improve it and change it. When I will go back from holiday. Have a nice day and thank you a lot for your help !! Matteo

Answer (score 0):

I think you could join the table back to itself to achieve this.

something like

```
select a.Name, a.ID, a.alias_1, b.alias_2

from table a join table b 
on a.ID = b.ID and a.alias_1 != 'Null' and b.alias_2 != 'Null'
```

although that might be a little heavy on the processing if you're working with large tables

Comment: I think it's a little bit more complicate because I already used MAX and CASE to Pivot the table. Before rotating the table, there s no null value, all rows is a duplicate row with a different date and I pivot it to have all the date in the same row. But Maybe my question was not well asked. I will improve it and change it. When I will go back from holiday. Have a nice day and thank you a lot for your help !! Matteo